# Error when defining length in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have defined a procedure named `length` in a file named `test.pl`:

```
% Finds the length of a list.
length([], 0).
length([_ | Tail], N) :-
    length(Tail, N1),
    N is 1 + N1.
```

When the program is run using SWI-Prolog (`prolog test.pl`), the following error appears:

```
ERROR: /home/user/test.pl:2:
    No permission to modify static procedure `length/2'
    Defined at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/init.pl:3496
ERROR: /home/user/test.pl:3:
    No permission to modify static procedure `length/2'
    Defined at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/init.pl:3496
```

I tried changing the name of the procedure from `length` to `mylength`, and the error disappears. What does this error mean? Can I define a procedure named `length`? If not, why can't it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

length/2 isn't defined in Prolog, but it's instead part of the shallow interface over native (high efficient) lists implementation. You should use the directive [redefine_system_predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=redefine_system_predicate/1).

For instance, save in a file redef_length.pl

```
:- redefine_system_predicate(length(?,?)).

% Finds the length of a list.
length([], 0).
length([_ | Tail], N) :-
    length(Tail, N1),
    N is 1 + N1.
```

then consult it

```
?- [test/prolog/redef_length].
true.

?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- length(A,B).
   Call: (8) length(_1476, _1478) ? creep
   Exit: (8) length([], 0) ? creep
A = [],
B = 0 ;
   Redo: (8) length(_1476, _1478) ? creep
   Call: (9) length(_1718, _1738) ? creep
   Exit: (9) length([], 0) ? creep
   Call: (9) _1478 is 1+0 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 1 is 1+0 ? creep
   Exit: (8) length([_1716], 1) ? creep
A = [_1716],
B = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

That's right. `length/2` is a [built-in predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=length/2): *length(?List, ?Int)* is True if *Int* represents the number of elements in *List*. So the name is already used.

Comment: There are also other predicates defined by SWI Prolog (e.g. `member`, `append`, etc.) that do not cause similar errors when I try to 'overwrite' them. Why does this only happen with `length`?

Comment: @Flux I don't know. The difference most likely responsible is that `member` and `append` are [part of the lists library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists), and your code takes precedence over autoloading. Another may be that you define, for example, `member/3` which has no conflict with the existing `member/2`.